# graphics card for the 3d modeling program solidworks

Tags: graphics-card, 3d-modeling, solidworks

I am building a computer for which I will be required to use the 3d modeling program solidworks. Initially the graphics card I was going was this one.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009LTUC90/ref=ox_sc_act_title_10?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009LTUC90)

Looking at the solidworks specs website

http://www.solidworks.com/sw/support/videocardtesting.html

it gives a list of approved video cards.  I guess question is if I plan on using solidworks, do I have to use one of these cards (from the website), or will the one I originally picked work?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much a crap shoot if a non-approved card will work within SolidWorks. I work at a place where we run Siemens NX instead of SolidWorks and we exclusively use Quadro cards. The card you picked out is a desktop card, not a workstation class card. Also, most of the CAD houses I've seen(Boeing, Lockheed) run on NVIDIA hardware, not AMD. Not sure why, but it's worth mentioning.

What many people don't realize is that the workstation class cards that some of these 3d modeling software call for contain extra logic specifically for CAD work. The difference physically between the desktop/workstation versions are slim, the workstation cards simply contain more OpenGL commands. That is what you are paying for when you get a workstation card at x2 the price of the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

We tried using a non-approved card and had issues with rendering.  We switched to the approved card and Solidworks driver and the program worked perfectly.  I would suggest staying with one from the approved list.  It will save you much frustration going forward.